# Decision tree ,information gain and overfitting

Tags: classification, data-mining, cart, decision-theory

If i use the **information gain** in order to evaluate the best split in a decision tree, why using a binomial split reduces the risk of overfitting ?

Is the **information gain** test misleading if we have a split with many branches ?